# how to clean advanced search form and refresh data

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

Good afternoon! I'm a newbie. I use the bootstrap-table project and the toolbar extension for it. The Toolbar allows you to sort the data using advancedSearch. When entering data in input, advancedSearch works. The sorting opens in a modal window. I want to create a custom button that will clear the form and update the data (clear filter). Before that, I created a custom Refresh button, but it doesn't work that way with advancedSearch.

```
    <table id="table-users" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
        <th data-field="username" data-sortable="true">Имя</th>
        <th data-field="fio" data-sortable="true">ФИО</th>
        <th data-field="company" data-sortable="true">Организация</th>
        <th data-field="department" data-sortable="true">Департамент</th>
        <th data-field="dolg" data-sortable="true">Должность</th>
        <th data-field="ismpi" data-sortable="true">МПИ</th>
        <th data-field="isbdm" data-sortable="true">БДМ</th>
        <th data-field="isowner" data-sortable="true">Заказчик</th>
        <th data-field="isarchitector" data-sortable="true">Архитектор</th>
        <th data-field="ispm" data-sortable="true">Руководитель портфеля</th>
        <th data-field="perm_viewrep" data-sortable="true">Видит все отчеты</th>
        <th data-field="perm_editrep" data-sortable="true">Админ шаблонов отчетов</th>
        <th data-field="perm_board" data-sortable="true">Видит дашборд</th>
        <th data-field="active" data-sortable="true">Активно</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script>
    $table = $('#table-users')

    $table.bootstrapTable({
        url: "{{ route('getUsers') }}",
        locale: 'ru-RU',
        cookie: 'true',
        cookieIdTable: 'table-users',
        search: 'true',
        advancedSearch: 'true',
        idTable: 'advancedTable',
        pagination: 'true',
        showRefresh: 'true',
        showFullscreen: 'true',
        showSearchClearButton : 'true',
        showColumns: 'true',
        showColumnsToggleAll: 'true',
        buttons: buttons(),
        buttonsOrder: ['advancedTab', 'userAdd', 'refresh' , 'fullscreen', 'columns', 'exportExcel', 'clearSearch'],
        icons: {refresh: 'fa-refresh', fullscreen: 'fa-arrows-alt', columns: 'fa-th-list', advancedSearchIcon: 'fa-search-plus', clearSearch: 'fa-trash'}
    });

    $('#btn-create-user').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{route('createUser')}}',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $('#create-user-form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    sg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    $msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                alert($msg);
            },
        });
    });

    function buttons () {
        return {
            userAdd: {
                text: 'Добавить пользователя',
                icon: 'fa-user',
                event: function () {
                    $('#modalCreateUser').modal('toggle')
                },
                attributes: {
                    title: 'Добавить пользователя'
                }
            },
            clearSearch: {
                text: 'Сброс параметров поиска',
                icon: 'fa-search-minus',
                event: function () {
                    $('#advancedSearch').trigger('reset')
                    $('#create-user-form').trigger('reset')
                    $table.bootstrapTable('advancedSearch'); //dont work
                    // example: $table.boostrap('refresh') its work for custom button for refresh data
                },
                attributes: {
                    title: 'Сброс параметров поиска'
                }
            },
            exportExcel: {
                text: 'Выгрузить в формате Excel',
                icon: 'fa-download',
                event: {

                },
                attributes: {
                    title: 'Выгрузить в формате Excel'
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: @Swati update code

Comment: Hi, is it possible for you to make this runnable ?

Comment: you can use https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/toolbar.html

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239932/bootstrap-table-advanced-search-show-all-rows-when-custom-button-is-clicked) will solve your issue .