# Bootstrap Table (Advanced Search)- Show all rows when custom button is clicked

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using `bootstrap-table` plugin . In this plugin i have added [data-advanced-search](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/toolbar/) for filtering rows depending on user input.
So, whenever **down arrow** button is clicked a modal gets open . In this modal there are inputs for all columns and whenever a user type in this input rows are getting filtered .This is working fine .

Now , i need to clear filter whenever user click on `clear` button to show all rows inside table again. So , to achieve this i have search inside `bootstrap-table-toolbar.min.js` file and found below code which is responsible for clearing search & showing rows . i.e :

```
n.default("#avdSearchModalContent_".concat(e.idTable)).append(this.createFormAvd().join("")), n.default("#".concat(e.idForm)).off("keyup blur", "input").on("keyup blur", "input", (function(n) {
   "server" === e.sidePagination ? t.onColumnAdvancedSearch(n) : (clearTimeout(o), o = setTimeout((function() { t.onColumnAdvancedSearch(n)
        }), e.searchTimeOut))
     })
```

One solution i came up to achieve this is to use `blur()` event on inputs inside modal so that above code will get called and as the value of input is `""` or `null` it will show all rows. This solution works if i have filtered rows using **only one input** inside modal else it doesn't work .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable()
})
$(document).on("click", "#custom_clear", function() {
  $("#advancedSearch input").val("")
  $("#advancedSearch input:first").trigger("blur") //this works if user type only on first input in modal
  //$("#advancedSearch input").trigger("blur")//this also doesn't work
  //i have try to loop through input but this doesn't work
  /* $("#advancedSearch input").each(function(i){
   $(this).trigger("blur")
   })*/

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="custom_clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
<table id="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-advanced-search="true" data-id-table="advancedTable" data-show-search-clear-button="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Item2</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/extensions/toolbar/bootstrap-table-toolbar.min.js"></script>
```

Can someone help me to solve this or Is there any other way to achieve above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the source code, I've extended `resetSearch` function to do that:

```js
BootstrapTable.prototype.resetSearch = function() {
  // reset default search input
  var $search = this.$toolbar.find('.search input');
  $search.val('');
  this.onSearch({
    currentTarget: $search
  });
  
  // reset advanced search input
  $(`#${this.options.idForm} input`).val('');
  this.filterColumnsPartial = {};
  if (this.options.sidePagination !== 'server') {
    this.options.pageNumber = 1;
    this.onSearch();
    this.updatePagination();
    this.trigger('column-advanced-search', {});
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable()
})
$(document).on("click", "#custom_clear", function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable('resetSearch');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-free.fontawesome.com/releases/latest/css/free.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="custom_clear" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
<table id="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-advanced-search="true" data-id-table="advancedTable" data-show-search-clear-button="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
      <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Item2</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/extensions/toolbar/bootstrap-table-toolbar.min.js"></script>
```

**Update:** Your code doesn't work because there is a timeout before the search when blur event triggered. If next blur event come, it clear that timeout and begin the new one so only change of the last blur calculated:

```
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
  this.onColumnAdvancedSearch(e);
}, o.searchTimeOut);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer .. Its working :) . Can you explain me why my code doesn't work ?

Comment: I see .. Thank you again   :)